# htacces rewrite url - redirect url to sub folder without www - oc

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect url to a sub folder without www. like,

If anyone type

> http://**WWW**.mywebsite.com/theme1/

Then, I want this result,

> http://mywebsite.com/theme1/ (without www)

theme1 is a folder.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R,QSA,L]
```

Comment: Okay adi bhai! glad could help.

Answer (score 0):

Dear This can be done via masking, you can use https://bitly.com/ to shorten your website url or you can use service provider such as GoDady, to get the same